# How do I make Debian start with IceWM-lite by default at startup?

Tags: debian, x11, icewm

On a Debian box, I have installed IceWM and IceWM-lite, I'd like it to boot with IceWM-lite by default.

So far I have done this through the desktop menu after each boot.

Comment: do you use display managers like gdm or lightdm ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNOME installed, you probably use `gdm` as display manager. Actually it should have remembered your default session, but you can do it manually by setting the file `~/.dmrc`:

`[Desktop]
Session=icewm
Language=en_US.UTF-8`

If you don't use display managers, add the following line to `~/.xinitrc`:

`exec icewm-session`